# Does the ATI Radeon Mobility HD 4250 count as UMA or not?

Tags: gpu

I need to order some replacement parts for my laptop (HP 625) and which audio I/O board I pick depends on whether my model has a system board "with UMA graphics subsystem" or not.

Could somebody please tell me whether the Mobility HD 4250 qualifies as such or not?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The AMD ATI Radeon HD 4250 (sometimes also ATI Mobility Radeon HD 4250 called) is an onboard (shared Memory) graphics chip in the RS880M chipset. It is based on the HD 3400 graphics core and features the UVD 2 video engine to decode HD videos. Compared to the HD 4200, the 4250 offers a similar performance, but the power consumption could be a bit better.

It uses a UMA.

You can also confirm this by looking at your power adapter.  According to [the HP 625 laptop user guide](http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c02585536.pdf) Page iii, as the UMA systems (considered "onboard graphics") come with a 65Watt adapter and systems with a dedicated graphics card have a 90Watt adapter.

Updated AC adapter part numbers:

613149-001–65-W AC adapter for use with computers with UMA graphics

613150-001–90-W AC adapter for use with computers with discrete graphic

Comment: If you have the specific model number, you can get the specifications for your exact built system including whether it is UMA as well.  go here:  http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/product?cc=us&dlc=en&lc=en&product=4173137